# PHP POST request to Youtube API: Getting server error

Tags: php, post, youtube

I am trying to use the Youtube API to automatically allow users to upload videos through browser-based uploading to Youtube.  Currently, I am working on doing a POST request through PHP, but without `curl`.  I don't have access to `curl` on the web server I am using.  The code I have so far is:

```
<?php

$theCode = $_GET['code'];

$urltopost = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$datatopost = http_build_query( array(
"code" => $theCode,
"client_id" => "312231647220287.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"client_secret" => "ULGrcIJOBfjka;dsfasdfyCd7Z5M",
"redirect_uri" => ".../youtubeTestCode/hello.php",
"grant_type" => "authorization_code"
));
$opts = array('http' =>
      array(
    'method => 'POST',
    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'header' => 'Host: accounts.google.com',
    'content' => $datatopost
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($urltopost, false, $context);

?>
```

I keep getting a server error though, when I try it out.

Comment: what is the error u getting ?

Comment: you're missing a quote `'` after `'method`

Comment: For me, it fails on `file_get_contents()`, are you sure the URL is valid ?

Comment: Before I was getting an HTTP 500 internal server error.  Now, that I fixed the quote piece and another quote piece, there is no error, but I think $result might not have anything in it.  It is supposed to be a JSON object, but I don't know if anything is actually coming back.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll add:

```
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

right after `get_file_content`, you'll see this:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Pragma: no-cache"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  [4]=>
  string(35) "Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 04:12:12 GMT"
  [5]=>
  string(30) "Content-Type: application/json"
  [6]=>
  string(31) "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
  [7]=>
  string(27) "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"
  [8]=>
  string(31) "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
  [9]=>
  string(11) "Server: GSE"
}
```

which means that your request is not well-constructed: 400 - bad request means authentication failure!

Comment: Thanks- I ran that on my script and saw a list of similar looking messages as well.  How would I find the part of my request that is not well constructed?

Comment: if you receive `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request` (first item in the array) it means that you have an authentication error.

Comment: OK - it looks like that is not happening anymore.  Unfortunately, now I am getting a 302 document moved error after my request.  It looks like HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token Content-Length: 224 Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 05:27:14 GMT Expires: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 05:27:14 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Connection: close

Comment: I already answered three of your questions (missing quote, debug response and 400 error), this is the forth, please start posting your questions separately.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I'm sorry for not posting separate questions.